# PHP Session disappear after navigate to a new page

Tags: php, session

Im having an issue with sessions for the past 2 months and before was working.
In all the pages the session is started with:

```
      session_start();
```

Every interaction i will use in the page it work. 
For example change the website language from english to portuguese.
After i navigate to another page the session is empty is not keep the session alive. This was working for the past 2 years. I already ask the server owner and there wasnt any update in the server.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to provide more examples of code where you use it and how you use it. In general you need to initiate session_start(); on every page you wanna access the values saved that way.

Comment: other that what Martin said, I think you are changing the domain name, and that is why probably old session is not accessible.

Comment: Are you using subdomains?

Comment: @Martin I have the session_start on every page that exists. This was working for the past 2 years and from 2 months ago it stop working.            And@Chayan is not a subdomain. But i can check with the server host company.